# Python Qt QListWidget Items Drag and Drop

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

How to move QListWidgetItem another row? Can i use drag and drop method?
Example:
    QListWiget items:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
```

item3 dragged and dropped. After:

```
item3
item1
item2
item4
```

I looked at this  [resource](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#dropMimeData) but i don't understand anything.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `dropMimeData` if all you need is internal drag&drop. That is used for things that are dropped from out of the widget. Item views (and their widget companions) come with internal drag/drop move implemented. You need to use [`InternalMove`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#DragDropMode-enum) for [`setDragDropMove`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#dragDropMode-prop).

Simple example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

lw = QtGui.QListWidget()
lw.setDragDropMode(lw.InternalMove)
for i in range(10):
    item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem('item %d' % i, lw)
lw.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Qt really should have a bold section in all their drag/drop stuff that if you want to simply move stuff around within a window, that is not the same as invoking the sometimes complex drag and drop mechanisms (using MIME data types) used to shuffle data between elements. The term 'drag and drop' is much more general than that, and a lot of people get confused by this. I know I did.